# Is it possible to stream the screen of an Ubuntu desktop to another device?

Tags: nvidia, streaming

I have an Ubuntu 18.04.2 installed in a desktop with a powerful nVidia GPU. I want to control it remotely from my Macbook, and be able to watch vides and  plays game. On Windows, solutions that work very well include Parsec and Dixper, softwares that use GPU acceleration to stream the screen of the computer to a different decide on the same network. It works very well.

Sadly, neither of those can use Ubuntu as the server. An alternative would be to use something like TeamViewer or VNC, but neither of those are designed for videos/gaming and the screen quality and input delays make them absolutely impractical for those use-cases.

Is there any way to stream the screen of an Ubuntu desktop to another device?

Answer (score 1):

[Steam Link](https://store.steampowered.com/steamlink/about/) is pretty much designed for the use case you're talking about.